# Reaching a file in a server through C# application

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I wrote an application in c# & SQLite for storing data of all employees in a company which has around 500 employees. I want to put the database & the application in a file server/shared folder (MS server). Then all employees will have a shortcut of the application in their desktops. I want to make some input fields (text box) enabled/disabled based on the permission of the user runs the application. Whats the best practice for doing that?

I want the user can read/write in the database through my application only (the application is located in the same database folder). I don't want the user to reach the database without my application. How to do that?

Comment: Bad idea. SQLLite is not suited for this. Use a database engine that can run as a db server instead (SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, ...), and deploy the application to each client machine instead of using a network share. Even better would be to go for a 3-tier architecture, but since you already wrote the application that may be too much work right now.

Comment: "I don't want the user to reach the database without my application." - This isn't possible with your choosen database engine.  A full database server would likely be a good choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't want the user to reach the database without my application

If your application will directly access the SQLite database via a Windows file share, this is impossible. Sure, you can make it inconvenient, but it's not really possible.

The only way to achieve this really is by introducing some middleware.

This would typically be a service (WCF perhaps) that listens for connections from your client application, authenticates them, and manages all access to the underlying database. The database would be stored in a location that is visible to the server only, and not visible through a Windows share to your users.

Also, SQLite isn't exactly a great choice for a multi-user system. You can kill two birds with one stone here - switch to a DBMS (MS SQL Server Express is free, also MySQL, PostgreSQL are common free choices) that accepts client connections over a network, and build your application to connect directly to the database server (using integrated Windows authentication may also be possible like this, so you can avoid an explicit logon). In a simple scenario this may be adequate and avoid you needing to build an explicit service layer.

In a more complex scenario, it can still make sense to have a middleware layer between the application and the database - this way, you can change the database design without changing the application design and deploying to all of your client machines - instead, just change the middleware layer in one place and your application won't know the difference.

Comment: MS SQL Server Express isn't the best multi-user system it certainly is not a good choice for 500 users.  A full copy of SQL Server would be an option of course.  MS SQL Server Express would be fine if the user needed a copy of the database on their machine to function.

Comment: Actually there's nothing about SQL Express that's not just fine for 500 users - if the database isn't big, and the computational requirements aren't large. For a small, simple database, on reasonably capable hardware, SQL Server Express will be just fine with 500 users.

Comment: Specifically, SQL Express 2012 is limited to utilising 4 cores on one CPU, 1GB of RAM, and a maximum database size of 10GB. That could easily be just fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the users to reach your database you should create a client server architecture.

You can run your service on the same machine as the file server (running as a Windows Service) and use WCF for communication between your server and your client. You access your database from your server and let your server authenticate your users and validate that they have access to the application.

You can cheat and try to "hide" database credentials inside your client application, but that is security by obscurity and any one with some programming skills or similar can find out the credentials to the database and connect directly to the database.